# Get friends' work data from facebook SDK on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I am trying to fetch work info for FB friends on iOS using Facebook SDK. Here's the code that I am using:

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"work", @"fields",
                                    nil];

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:
     ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             if (result) {
                 if (result.count) {
                     NSMutableArray *friendsWithJobTitles = [NSMutableArray array];
                     for (id aFriend in [result objectForKey:@"data"]) {
                         if ([aFriend objectForKey:@"work"]) {
                             [friendsWithJobTitles addObject:aFriend];
                         }


                     }

                    NSLog(@"result = %@", friendsWithJobTitles);
                 }
             }


         }
     }];
}
```

The friendsWithJobTitles is always blank for some reason. Please help.